# Is this divide-and-conquer algorithm O(n)?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562513/16759116) I came up with a divide-and-conquer algorithm about all subarrays of length k of an array of length n. Outline:

```
function solve(array, k):
   if array shorter than k:
      return default value
   left = solve(left half of array, k)
   right = solve(right half of array, k)
   middle_crossing = combine(left half of array, right half of array, k)
   return max(left, right, middle_crossing)
```

Make the array a "view" or a begin/end index pair, so passing an array half is O(1). And the `combine` operation takes O(k).

At first sight its structure looks like for example mergesort, so might take O(n log n). But it's faster for two reasons:

- The recursion doesn't go all the way down to length 1. Only to length k.
- The `combine` operation doesn't take O(n), only O(k).

So we have this runtime:

```
T(n) = { 2 * T(n/2) + O(k)    if n >= k
       { O(1)                 otherwise
```

I believe the total runtime is T(n) = O(n). One way to I think prove it:

We recurse only down to length k. So instead of finding the runtime `T(n)` as number of element-operations given n elements, consider the array of n elements as an array of n/k *blocks* of k elements each, and find the runtime `B(n)` as number of *block*-operations. Since each block-operation takes O(k) time, we have:

```
T(n) = B(n/k) * O(k)
B(m) = 2 * B(m/2) + O(1)
```

Master theorem (or just thinking) gives `B(m) = O(m)` and thus we have:

```
T(n) = B(n/k) * O(k) = O(n/k) * O(k) = O(n)
```

Is that right? Is it O(n), and is my proof correct? And does this *"consider blocks"* technique have a name (I haven't seen it before)? Or is there a better way to prove it?

Comment: The idea is interesting, but one thing to beware of is that the constants may be different for each "block". So even if each block takes $O(m)$, summing them up could potentially *not* be $O(n)$. So in order to apply this technique you will have to be much more careful - I doubt it will be easier than using a standard technique.

Comment: @nirshahar You mean my `O(k)` in `2 * T(n/2) + O(k)` and my `O(1)` in `2 * B(m/2) + O(1)`, right? I guess I was sloppy there. I see the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form) says "f(n)" at that place, i.e., a certain fixed function. Don't know whether it does that because it talks about it. I thought that's how mine would be understood as well, always same constant. I could rewrite it with an `f`, it's true for the algorithm. I'd say something like that, and also showing such a "standard technique", would be good as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily compute the height $h$ and the total number of nodes in the recurrence tree. After $h-1$ levels, the size of the subproblem is at least $k$ and at most $2k$. Therefore, $n/2^{h-1} \geq k$ after $h-1$ levels. Thus, we get the height of the tree at most $\log (n/k)+1$. Furthermore, the total nodes in the recurrence tree is at most $O(2^{\log n/k+1}) = O(n/k)$.

At every node of the tree, the algorithm is doing $O(k)$ operations. Therefore, the overall running time is $O(n)$

Comment: Yes, looks good now. I myself had handwavingly used something like "n/(2^h) is approximately k", good enough to fairly convince myself, but I appreciate seeing how it's done more precisely.

Comment: Have you seen nir shahar's comment and my reply under the question? I wonder whether the same issue applies to your *"At every node of the tree, the algorithm is doing O(k) operations"*. Or is your usage ok, different because you say "O(k)" once, from kind of a "global outside perspective" rather than *inside* the recurrence relation, so it's clearer that it means the same constant at every node?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Yes it is the same constant at every node. However, I am doubtful about your bucketing technique, i.e. `T(n) = B(n/k) * O(k).` Note that there are total $n-k$ buckets (or subarrays) technically, so I am not sure if the statement `T(n) = B(n/k) * O(k).` makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I know we both mean the same constant at every node. My question is whether that is understood that way. I'm not sure whether/where it needs to be stated explicitly.

Comment: With my blocks and my `T(n) = B(n/k) * O(k)`, I'm imprecise again, and I guess unclear. What I mean is *non-overlapping* blocks. Like *"without loss of generality, assume `n = 2^i * k` for a natural number i"*. In which case the lowest workful level of the call tree has exactly `n/k = 2^i` nodes, each with a subarray of exactly k elements. Those are the "blocks" I mean. I think the idea is correct, but I didn't make it clear and didn't justify the "without loss of generality".

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Oh, I see what you mean. But then, it is wrong to say that each block takes $O(k)$ time since the lowest level blocks take $O(1)$ time. I think your direction is correct but it requires more rigorous claims.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "lowest *workful* level", meaning the lowest level where real work is done (i.e., not the "return default value" branch). And technically, everything that is O(1) is also O(k), so it's not really wrong. But yes, in my proof I rather ignored these trivial calls/nodes, as I think it's clear that their O(1) time doesn't matter. I also could've written the pseudocode to actually not do another recursive call at all if the *half* array is too short. (Btw not trying to "defend" my proof, just explaining my thoughts. I appreciate you pointing out what's not good.)